# colcon build on ROS2 humble outputs "listing git files failed - pretending there aren't any"

Tags: ros2, build, colcon, git

I started to learn ros2, installed ros2 humble, have followed the tutorial of the channel [Robotics Back-End](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBGZ8LEvkCY&list=PLLSegLrePWgJudpPUof4-nVFHGkB62Izy&index=4) before and I was able to successfully create a node.

After some time I wanted to visit the tutorial again and started working on it, but I have been facing "listing git files failed - pretending there aren't any" error on colcon build. I had my_robot_controller node before and I wanted to add a fresh new node called my_robot_controller_2.

This is the output of `colcon build --event-handlers console_direct+` command on the workspace

```
Starting >>> my_robot_controller
Starting >>> my_robot_controller_2
running develop
running develop
running egg_info
writing ../../build/my_robot_controller/my_robot_controller.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to ../../build/my_robot_controller/my_robot_controller.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to ../../build/my_robot_controller/my_robot_controller.egg-info/entry_points.txt
writing requirements to ../../build/my_robot_controller/my_robot_controller.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to ../../build/my_robot_controller/my_robot_controller.egg-info/top_level.txt
running egg_info
writing ../../build/my_robot_controller_2/my_robot_controller_2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to ../../build/my_robot_controller_2/my_robot_controller_2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to ../../build/my_robot_controller_2/my_robot_controller_2.egg-info/entry_points.txt
writing requirements to ../../build/my_robot_controller_2/my_robot_controller_2.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to ../../build/my_robot_controller_2/my_robot_controller_2.egg-info/top_level.txt
listing git files failed - pretending there aren't any
listing git files failed - pretending there aren't any
reading manifest file '../../build/my_robot_controller/my_robot_controller.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file '../../build/my_robot_controller/my_robot_controller.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build
running build_py
running install
running install_lib
running install_data
running install_egg_info
removing '/home/u28i31/ros2_ws/install/my_robot_controller/lib/python3.10/site-packages/my_robot_controller-0.0.0-py3.10.egg-info' (and everything under it)
Copying ../../build/my_robot_controller/my_robot_controller.egg-info to /home/u28i31/ros2_ws/install/my_robot_controller/lib/python3.10/site-packages/my_robot_controller-0.0.0-py3.10.egg-info
running install_scripts
reading manifest file '../../build/my_robot_controller_2/my_robot_controller_2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file '../../build/my_robot_controller_2/my_robot_controller_2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build
running build_py
running install
running install_lib
running install_data
running install_egg_info
removing '/home/u28i31/ros2_ws/install/my_robot_controller_2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/my_robot_controller_2-0.0.0-py3.10.egg-info' (and everything under it)
Copying ../../build/my_robot_controller_2/my_robot_controller_2.egg-info to /home/u28i31/ros2_ws/install/my_robot_controller_2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/my_robot_controller_2-0.0.0-py3.10.egg-info
running install_scripts
Installing draw_circle script to /home/u28i31/ros2_ws/install/my_robot_controller/lib/my_robot_controller
Installing test_node script to /home/u28i31/ros2_ws/install/my_robot_controller/lib/my_robot_controller
writing list of installed files to '/home/u28i31/ros2_ws/build/my_robot_controller/install.log'
writing list of installed files to '/home/u28i31/ros2_ws/build/my_robot_controller_2/install.log'
--- stderr: my_robot_controller
listing git files failed - pretending there aren't any
---
Finished <<< my_robot_controller [1.81s]
--- stderr: my_robot_controller_2
listing git files failed - pretending there aren't any
---
Finished <<< my_robot_controller_2 [1.81s]

Summary: 2 packages finished [1.97s]
  2 packages had stderr output: my_robot_controller my_robot_controller_2
```

This is the result of `pip3 list | grep colcon`

```
colcon-argcomplete                   0.3.3
colcon-bash                          0.4.2
colcon-cd                            0.1.1
colcon-cmake                         0.2.27
colcon-common-extensions             0.3.0
colcon-core                          0.12.1
colcon-defaults                      0.2.8
colcon-devtools                      0.2.3
colcon-installed-package-information 0.1.0
colcon-library-path                  0.2.1
colcon-metadata                      0.2.5
colcon-mixin                         0.2.3
colcon-notification                  0.2.15
colcon-output                        0.2.13
colcon-override-check                0.0.1
colcon-package-information           0.3.3
colcon-package-selection             0.2.10
colcon-parallel-executor             0.2.4
colcon-pkg-config                    0.1.0
colcon-powershell                    0.3.7
colcon-python-setup-py               0.2.8
colcon-recursive-crawl               0.2.1
colcon-ros                           0.3.23
colcon-test-result                   0.3.8
colcon-zsh                           0.4.0
```

A previous solution suggests to change the dashes in `setup.cfg` files to underscores but they are already with underscores.

```
[develop]
script_dir=$base/lib/my_package
[install]
install_scripts=$base/lib/my_package
```

If it helps, these lines are in my ~/.bashrc

```
source <(ng completion script)
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
source /usr/share/colcon_argcomplete/hook/colcon-argcomplete.bash
source ~/ros2_ws/install/setup.bash
```

Is there anything that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same issue while following the ROS 2 service client tutorial. Initially, I attempted the workaround suggested in this [ROSanswers post](https://answers.ros.org/question/402985/ros2-following-basic-serviceclient-tutorial-executables-doesnt-seems-to-install/), but it didn't resolve my problem.

The root cause of the issue was the presence of the `setuptools_scm` package. Colcon was using `setuptools_scm` instead of the traditional `setuptools`. To determine if you have `setuptools_scm` installed, you can use the following command:

```bash
pip3 list | grep setuptools
```

In my case, I completely removed the package because it wasn't useful for me.

```bash
pip3 uninstall setuptools-scm
```

In addition, make sure that you are using `setuptools 58.2.0`. In case you can install this specific version.

```bash
pip3 install setuptools==58.2.0
```

This worked for me. Let me know if encounter any issues.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much :)